# Javascript cell color according to math

Tags: javascript, html, math

I have an html table with numbers. For example:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
 5    3    1
 1    2    1
 10   3    2
```

And I want to use Javascript in order each cell has a specific color background according to the following math:
if one of the three columns (for each row) is greater than the sum of the other 2 columns
for example:

```
Col1 > Col2 + Col3 => bkg color: #000
Col2 > Col1 + Col3 => bkg color: #333
Col3 > Col1 + Col3 => bkg color: #666
```

Can I do it with Javascript? Can anyone help with the code?

Comment: Can you show your code what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something for you (http://jsfiddle.net/AbnCz/3/). This doesn't scale that well as an algo, but works as per your requirements. If you end up adding more rows/cols, add the appropriate colors in the `colors` array.

*> update: made a perf update to cache the sum as opposed to determining it through each cell traversal*

## HTML

```
<table id="dataTable">
    <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>70</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>60</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

## Javascript

```
var colors = ["#000","#333","#666"];
var t = document.getElementById('dataTable');

var rows = t.getElementsByTagName('tr'), row, cells, tgtCell, rowSum, othersSum;

// let's go through the rows
for(var r=0; r<rows.length; r++){

   row = rows[r];
   cells = row.getElementsByTagName('td');
   rowSum = 0;

   // lets get the sum for the row.
   // we'll subtract each cell from it to get the remaining sum.
   for(var _c=0; _c<cells.length; _c++){
       rowSum += parseInt(cells[_c].textContent,10);
   }

   // let's go through the cells
   for(var c=0; c<cells.length; c++){

       tgtCell = cells[c];
       tgtVal = parseInt(tgtCell.textContent, 10);

       othersSum = rowSum - tgtVal;

       // if the target is greater than the remaining sum, style it
       if(tgtVal > othersSum){
           tgtCell.style.backgroundColor = colors[c % colors.length];           
       }

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code myself. But it should be something like this:

```
 var table = document.getElementById("table"); //Replace "table" with the id of your table in the HTML
    var table = document.getElementById("table"); //Replace "table" with the id of your table in the HTML
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++)   //iterate through rows
{

    var cell1 = row.cells[0];
    var cell2 = row.cells[1];
    var cell3 = row.cells[2];

    if(parseFloat(cell1.innerHTML) > (parseFloat(cell2.innerHTML) + parseFloat(cell3.innerHTML)))
    {   
        cell1.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
    }
    if(parseFloat(cell2.innerHTML) > parseFloat(cell3.innerHTML) + parseFloat(cell1.innerHTML))
    {
        cell2.style.backgroundColor = "#333";
    }
    if(parseFloat(cell3.innerHTML) > parseFloat(cell2.innerHTML) + parseFloat(cell1.innerHTML))
    {
        cell3.style.backgroundColor = "#666";
    }
}
```

You may need to use parseInt or parseFloat on the row.cells to convert the text to a number.

Comment: Thank you @Asagohan for the reply! My table id is "id='myTable'". So i customised your code to ensure that is working, as following:

var table = document.getElementById("myTable"); //Replace "table" with the id of your table in the HTML
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++)   //iterate through rows
{
  row.cells[10].style.backgroundColor = "#000";
}

but nothing happened. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that this code will work only if all numbers are positive

Comment: @DragosBobolea yes! all my numbers will be >=0

Comment: As @Asagohan said, you have to convert the values to numbers.
Add something like
    `var cell0 = parseFloat(row.cells[0]); 
    //same for the other
    if(cell0 > cell1 + cell2)
    //bla bla bla`

Comment: I have updated the code to use parseInt. Try it now. Also have a look at getting firebug for firefox which you can use to debug your code to see what is going on.

Comment: I have tested the code and it works. You can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Vkj89/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

HTML:

```
<table id="dataTable">
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>16</td>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
var table = document.getElementById('dataTable'), activeCells
                    row = table.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
                    cell = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

                var colorArray = new Array('red', 'blue', 'yellow');

                //loop through all rows
                for ( var i = 0; i < row.length; ++i) {

                    //get cells currently being read
                    activeCells = row[i].getElementsByTagName('td');

                    //prepare storage
                    var cellArray = new Array(),
                        newCellArray = new Array(),
                        cellElementArray = new Array(),
                        sum = 0;

                    //loop through active cells
                    for ( var x = 0; x < activeCells.length; ++x ) {

                        var currentCell = activeCells[x],
                            cellVal = parseInt( currentCell.innerHTML );

                        cellArray[x] = cellVal;
                        newCellArray[x] = cellVal;

                        cellElementArray[x] = currentCell;

                    }

                    //loop through Cell Array
                    for ( var y = 0; y < cellArray.length; ++y ) {

                        newCellArray.splice(y, 1);

                        for ( var z = 0; z < newCellArray.length; ++z ) {
                            sum += newCellArray[z];
                        }

                        newCellArray = [];

                        for ( var n = 0; n < cellArray.length; ++n ) {
                            newCellArray[n] = cellArray[n];
                        }

                        console.log( sum);

                        if ( cellArray[y] > sum ) {

                            console.log( 'in');

                            cellElementArray[y].style.backgroundColor = colorArray[y];
                        }

                        sum = 0;

                    }
                }
```

An additional feature that I implemented is that this is dynamic. Try to increase the number of cells and it will still calculate.

And please change the colorArray according to your preference. It is by column ordered. something like `var colorArray = new Array('#000','#333','#667');`

jsfiddle demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/aVqCU/